# Number of days with traffic intensity from tuples in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I'm trying to write a function that uses another function called traffic_intensity and takes a list of tuples, returning the number of days with the given traffic intensity. This is what I have at the moment:

```
def traffic_intensity(count):
    """Returns string indicating intensity level given by number of 
    vehicles"""
    level_name = ""
    if(count < 5000):
        level_name = "Very Low"
    elif(count >= 5000 and count < 10000):
        level_name = "Low"
    elif(count >= 10000 and count < 18000):
        level_name = "Moderate"
    elif(count >= 18000):
        level_name = "High"
    return(level_name)    

def n_days_at_intensity(vehicle_records, intensity):
    """Returns number of days with the given traffic intensity level"""
    days = 0
    for number in intensity:
        traffic =  traffic_intensity(number)
        if traffic == intensity:
            days+= 1
    return days
```

This is currently giving me an error
But it is supposed to return me an output of

```
3
```

for the test code:

```
vehicle_records = [('2010-01-01',1),
                   ('2010-01-02',2),
                   ('2010-01-03',3)]
days = n_days_at_intensity(vehicle_records, 'Very Low')
print(days)
```

and an output of 
    0

for test code

```
voiture_records = [('2010-01-01',1),
                   ('2010-01-02',2),
                   ('2010-01-03',3)]
days = n_days_at_intensity(voiture_records, 'Moderate')
print(days)
```

Can someone please tell me how my code can be fixed to get these outputs?

Comment: `count` is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `n_days_at_intensity`, the `vehicle_records` you passed in is a `list of tuples`. Try looping through the `list of tuples` as below:

```
def n_days_at_intensity (vehicle_records, intensity):
    """Returns number of days with the given traffic intensity level"""
    days = 0

    # loop through list of  tuples
    for r in vehicle_records:
        r_date = r[0]
        r_count = r[1]

        traffic = traffic_intensity(r_count)
        if traffic == intensity:
            days += 1

    return days
```

Then calling the below should returns `3`:

```
vehicle_records = [('2010-01-01',1),
                   ('2010-01-02',2),
                   ('2010-01-03',3)]
days = n_days_at_intensity(vehicle_records, 'Very Low')
print(days)
```